Validating AUC Calculation for a Multiple Linear Regression Model
I am trying to calculate the AUC value of multiple linear regression model (two variables) ,so i was working on the following code and wanted to confirm with you.
I have two variables named Sa_T1 and Sa_07 ,x and y axis respectively and in the z axis i have log_EDPs , i did use multiple linear regression to determine the following relationship:
log_EDPs = coef_log_Sa_T1 * log_Sa_T1 + coef_log_Sa_07 * log_Sa_07 + intercept
which results the following values, 0.3364, 0.6530 , -7.1452 respectively . now i am  want to calculate the AUC and i developped the following code based on my previous code of one variable case:
# Coefficients
coef_log_Sa_T1 = 0.3364
coef_log_Sa_07 = 0.6530
intercept = -7.1452

# Predicted log(edp) using the regression model
predicted_log_edp = coef_log_Sa_T1 * log_Sa_T1 + coef_log_Sa_07 * log_Sa_07 + intercept

#  log(edp) based on a threshold
threshold_SA = np.log(np.median(log_EDPs))
y_true = (log_EDPs >= threshold_SA).astype(int)  


y_pred_binary = (predicted_log_edp >= threshold_SA).astype(int)


y_pred_prob = (predicted_log_edp - predicted_log_edp.min()) / (predicted_log_edp.max() - predicted_log_edp.min())  

# Calculate AUC based on predicted probabilities
auc_prob = roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred_prob)
print(f"AUC (probabilities): {auc_prob}")

which results the AUC value of 0.9802.
Is the code doing the right calculation?
